# How to import spring Java dsl config into XML configuration?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I couldn't import java dsl config into XML configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class JavaApplicationContext {

  @MessagingGateway
  public interface helloService {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "requestChnl")
    public String sayHello(String msg);
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow helloIntFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("requestChnl")
                           .transform(new GenericTransformer<String, String>() {

                            @Override
                            public String transform(String source) {
                              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                              return "Hello "+source;
                            }})
                           .get();
  }


}
```

Inside XML config, i have `<bean id="hellGtwy" class="com.example.JavaApplicationContext" />`

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'helloIntFlow' defined in
>   com.example.JavaApplicationContext: Initialization of bean failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'org.springframe
>   work.integration.config.SplitterFactoryBean#6': FactoryBean threw
>   exception on object creation; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An AbstractReplyPr
>   oducingMessageHandler may only be referenced once (MY_SPLITTER_ID) -
>   use scope="prototype"

I couldnt relate the exception with my code. I have no splitter in the java dsl config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually an advice from Spring team to inject XML config into Java & annotation configuration via `@ImportResource`.

From other side `MY_SPLITTER_ID` isn't related to Spring Integration Java DSL, too. The can be even with XML config.

Try to play with `<component-scan>` instead of raw `<bean>`, if you'd like to have an annotation configuration together with XML one.

Comment: In my application, xml config is the parent. So I have to put my java config inside xml. So @ImportResource is ruled out in my case.  I tried both <component-scan> and <bean> both didnt work. Surprising thing is if i remove the <bean id="hellGtwy" class="com.example.JavaApplicationContext" />, code compiles successfully. So something in the java dsl is the reason..  Also exception seems misleading..

Comment: OK. Have you tried to figure out what is `MY_SPLITTER_ID`? How about to import just empty `@Configuration` without any `IntegrationFlow` definition?

Comment: Empty @Configuration working fine. If I add the integrationFlow, above issue comes.  MY_SPLITTER_ID is present in different integration flow not related to this. We have many splitter in the configuration, but dont know this one alone causing this issue. But i don't see any difference with other splitter.

Comment: <int:splitter id="MY_SPLITTER_ID" input-channel="MY_SPLITTER_SPLITTER_CHANNEL" 
    ref="networkSyncDataSplitter" output-channel="MY_SPLITTER_REQTRACK_RCVD_CHANNEL">
   </int:splitter>

Comment: Above is the splitter configuration we have used in the xml. Also do you know why helloIntFLow try to create splitter bean?

Comment: Show more stack trace, please, and make the simple test-case. Looks like a bug in the framework

Comment: Sure will try to do. But I ran samples with one xml splitter and imported java dsl config into it. It didnt throw me error. I ll try to replicate it and let you know.

Comment: The error implies that the bean `networkSyncDataSplitter` is an `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler` implementation and is referenced from two (or more) components. A DEBUG log for `org.springframework` (bean creation) should point you to the culprit.

Comment: I have added scope="prototype" for that nwSyncSplitter bean, then it works. But what is the reason if i remove the helloIntflow, it worked earlier and if i add, it didnt. Also i have searched my entire workspace, only in the MY_SPLITTER_ID splitter it is used.